# passing a varriable into a javascript function

Tags: javascript

i want to pass a varriable "templateBody " into a function is it possible ?
This my code

```
function GetMenu(){
 var templates = [{name:"maher",body:"<p>Maher test</p>"},{name:"Jeremy",body:"<p>Jeremy test</p>"}]
 var payload = []
 for (var i = 0; i<templates.length; i++){
   var templateBody = templates[i].body
     payload.push({
       text : templates[i].name,
       onclick: function(templateBody){tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, templateBody);}
 })
}
return payload
}
```

Comment: You'll need a proper closure for that.

Comment: don't forget to put semi colons after variable declarations and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only pass a variable if you are calling the function. But you are not. However, since all JavaScript functions are closures, you still have access to any variable defined in a higher scope. There is nothing special to do.

The issue with your code is that you are *shadowing* the *variable* `templateBody` with the *parameter* `templateBody`. Remove it:

```
function(templateBody) -> function()
```

The other issue is that you are creating a function inside a loop. That doesn't work very well with closures, but there are solutions: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/218196)

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
function(templateBody){
  tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, templateBody);
}
```

Given the name of the property, I expect this is to be called when the `onclick` event fires. Which will inject the event into the function as templateBody, it won't use the templateBody defined above.

Moreover, the templateBody is being used as a closure inside a loop, which means it won't remain the same for the defined functions. You need a proper closure pattern like this:

```
(function(templateBody){
  return function() {
    tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, templateBody);
  }
})(templateBody);
```

Comment: *"You need a proper closure pattern like this:"* The original function already is a "proper" closure. The solution is to create an additional scope in the loop body, which has nothing to do with closures.

Comment: It's not a closure that fits the problem, hence not a proper closure. That's what I meant.